# What Javascript engine is used by Paw?

Tags: paw-app

I've been trying my hand at writing some code generator extensions. Using "regular" Javascript these work fine so I decided to up the ante and convert them to ES2015 and/or TypeScript based projects. However the transpiled code cannot always be registered as a Paw extension. So this got me wondering: what Javascript engine is actually running under the hood? Should it be able to talk native ES6 code? Is this planned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paw links against Apple's official JavaScript Core framework, as it can be found in:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/`

And Safari is also linked against it. You can find the actual `jsc` binary here:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/jsc`

It sounds like all [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (=ES2015) tests pass except promises: [test262/CONSOLE-RUNNER.md](https://github.com/tc39/test262/blob/master/CONSOLE-RUNNER.md#async-tests)

My guess is as features are added on Safari, at each OS upgrade, they are also added to the JavaScript Core framework. So the exact ECMA compatibility probably depends on the OS version.

Comment: That might explain it; Safari 8 is still lightyears behind: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#safari71_8

Comment: Yes, and definitely no ES6 :(